# EdgeNGramFilterFactory still giving no results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I followed the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot) to get Sunspot running and then this [tutorial](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/djcp/2011/10/fulltext-wildcard-searching-with-rubyrails-and-sunspot/) on enabling wildcard searching on my search field but for some reason it still isn't working.

Inside of my solr/conf/schema.xml I replaced the default lines with these instead for the EdgeNGramFilterFactory:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When I search for "ste" or "steve jobs" I get Steve Jobs, but when I try "stv jbs" or stv jobs" I get no results.

I reindexed and restarted the sunspot server a couple of times ( also the rails server).

Am I missing something here? What could be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) basically creates n-grams for the terms.

So for `steve jobs` with min gram size as 1 the following tokens would be generated -

```
s, st, ste, stev, steve, steve j, steve jo, steve job, steve jobs
```

As in your case searching for `stv jbs` or `stv jobs` are more of an misspellings rather than partial matches, and would not match the documents.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Also, can sunspot do what I am looking for with finding words like "stve" and "jbs", is their a method for that like the EdgeNGramFilter?

Comment: nope. Unless you use phonetic filters or synonyms these searches wont match the results.

Comment: Worth noting, for precision's sake, that each term is analyzed separately. So that's `s, st, ste, stev, …` and, separately, `j, jo, job, jobs`.